# pyspark dataframe make the map values using column name

Tags: python, pyspark

I have data frame as below first one in pyspark dataframe.
Without change to pandas Df, I need to chage the dataframe like the second one with map values.
Does anyone have an idea for this job?

```
    a   b
A   1   2
B   4   2

↓
    value
A   {a : 1, b : 2}
B   {a : 4, b: 2}
```

Comment: In plain pandas you'd use [`df.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Comment: this is in pyspark dataframe! @smci

Comment: I know, I'm suggesting you find the equivalent. Even knowing the pandas equivalent should help you.

Comment: ...actually [`df.to_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `struct` and then convert it into a JSON field using `to_json` method.

## Working Example

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 4, "b": 2}])

df.withColumn("value", F.to_json(F.struct(*[F.col(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns]))).select("value").show()
```

### Output

```
+-------------+
|        value|
+-------------+
|{"a":1,"b":2}|
|{"a":4,"b":2}|
+-------------+
```